# Conditions for a bipartite graph

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, bipartite-graphs

Is a 8 vertices graph with degree $3$ and $12$ edges a bipartite graph? For instance, $24$ is the sum of degree and it is twice the number of edges and theorem 1 it says any graph is bipartite if the sum of the degree of all vertices is equal to twice the number of edges. The problem is that when I give the partition some of the vertices are adjacent to each other and even if they are in the same set. Like $V1 = \{a,c,f,h\}$ and $V2 = \{b,d,e,g\}$ and $a$ is adjacent to $h$ or $e$ is adjacent to $d$. Does it matter if they are adjacent in the same set?

Comment: The theorem you state is called the [handshaking lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handshaking_lemma) which is true for any finite undirected graph, not necessarily bipartite.

Comment: Thank you very much , it was very helpful! Basically any graph is bipartite if it is proved based on this theorem. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: No, this theorem is true for any finite undirected graph, so it doesn't imply anything about the graph being bipartite. Take your favorite finite undirected non-bipartite graph and check that this theorem holds true for it.

Comment: Yes I applied this in a finite undirected graph and this theorem stands. Is this theorem enough to prove the graph is bipartite?

Comment: This theorem is a general theorem you can prove for every possible graph and it isn't related to being bipartite

Answer (score 1):

This graph can be both bipartite and unbipartite and the info you gave isn't enough to decide whether it is or it isn't. The only theorem about bipartite graphs based on their properties is that the graph $G$ is bipartite iff it doesn't have any odd cycles and clearly your graph can be of both types.
For a example of a bipartite graph of this type, draw four vertices $A_1,A_2,A_3,A_4$ in the first set and $B_1,B_2,B_3,B_4$ in the second set. Then connect $A_1$ to $B_2,B_3,B_4$ , connect $A_2$ to $B_1,B_3,B_4$ , etc. and the graph is bipartite. For the opposite, make a $C_4$ with $A_1,A_2,B_1,B_2$ and another $C_4$ with the other vertices and it will be unbipartite because it has several cycles of length 3.

Comment: To complete my information, the graph has 8 vertices 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 where 1 is adjacent to 2,5,8 and 3 is adjacent to 2,4,7 and 6 is adjacent to 2,5,7 and 8 is adjacent 1,4,5 and 2 is adjacent 1,3,6 and 4 is adjacent 3,5,8 and 5 is adjacent to 4,6,8 and 7 is adjacent to 3,6,8.

Comment: Oh so you mean of a special graph. Your graph isn't bipartite because of having several cycles of length 3 such as $8,4,5$.

Comment: Thank you very much Aryan!

Comment: My pleasure :))

Comment: Please upvote to my question, I don't know why there is 3 downvotes and I think the question is so clear.

Comment: Probably it's random people thinking this was too trivial not knowing that's not what downvotes are for!

Comment: @kenzie: it's funny how you ask this person to upvote this question but not upvote/accept an answer that helped you. The downvotes are probably because of lack of context. You say "theorem 1" but not quote the textbook/paper you're using. Also, you misunderstood the theorem you quoted yourself and weren't reading the responses completely before replying.

Answer (score 1):

The theorem I think you are talking about doesn't have anything to do with whether a graph is bipartite or not - its the [*handshaking lemma*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handshaking_lemma) which just observes that the sum of the vertex degrees must count all the edges twice.

Graphs where every vertex has the same degree are called [*regular*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_graph). If all the vertices have degree $k$ they are $k$-regular and in particular $3$-regular graphs are called [*cubic*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_graph).

Typically, knowing the [degree sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_(graph_theory)#Degree_sequence) of a graph (which gives the degree of every vertex) is not enough to establish whether or not it is [bipartite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipartite_graph) - that usually requires knowing  how the vertices are connected, since - to specifically answer a question there - the defining quality of a bipartite graph is that there are *no* connections between nodes in the same part.

Here's a couple of graphs that fit your description - one is bipartite, one is not. In the bipartite graph on the left, the red nodes are only ever connected to blue nodes and vice-versa. I've highlighted a cycle of length $5$ in the non-bipartite graph, since you never find odd-length cycles in bipartite graphs - it would be impossible to make the colouring described for the other graph.

[image]